# Add a model transformer that transforms multiple fields in embedded form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to read a `\DateInterval` from 2 input fields, as follows :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => "Name"])
        ->add('duration', DateIntervalType::class, ['label' => false])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => NamedInterval::class]);
}
```

Here's my `DateIntervalType::buildForm` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('amount', IntegerType::class)
        ->add('kind', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => ['Year' => 'Y', 'Month' => 'M', 'Week' => 'W']])
    ;
}
```

And here is the transformer I attempted :

```
$builder->get('duration')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    function ($property) {
        return new \DateInterval('P' . $property['amount'] . $property['kind']);
    },
    function ($property) {
        /* compute $specString from $property assuming it's a \DateInterval */
        /* ... */
        return ['amount' => 1, 'kind' => 'W'];
    }
));
```

Hence this is not working, my `$property` is always `null` after validating the form when transforming from form data to `\DateInterval` and I'm not even sure that I ever used the transformer from `\DateInterval` to form data, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `CallbackTransformer` is inversed :

```
$builder->get('duration')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
    function ($property) {
        /* compute specString from $property assuming it's a \DateInterval */
        /* ... */
        return ['amount' => 1, 'kind' => 'W'];
    },
    function ($property) {
        if (!$property) return null;
        return new \DateInterval('P' . $property['amount'] . $property['kind']);
    }
));
```

Now it works like a charm !

EDIT: as `\DateInterval` converts weeks to days, there also should be an option `'Day' => 'D'` in the options list.

Comment: A model transformer transforms from the model format to the norm format (in your case that's from a `DateInterval` object to an array). This is done using the `transform()` method. The `CallbackTransformer` calls the first callback here. To do the transformation from the norm data back to the model data the `reverseTransform()` method is used (i.e. the second callback passed to the `CallbackTransformer`).